# Where is an example of a Complex ASP.net MVC model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm looking for an example of a more complex asp.net **mvc** model. All of the Models I've seen on the ASP.net site are very, very simple and involve only one or two database tables.

I'm curious as to how **mvc** works with more complex models with many tables and ternary relationships.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here a a few mvc applications with varying levels of complexity. Checkout Kazi's blog there is some awesome stuff there! Also checkout the ncommon which has repository paterns etc for nhibernate, linq2sql and entity framework, among other goodies.

1. [kigg](http://www.codeplex.com/Kigg) from [Kazi Manzur Rashid](http://weblogs.asp.net/rashid/)
2. [sutekishop](http://code.google.com/p/sutekishop/) from [Mike Hadlow](http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/)
3. [codecampserver](http://code.google.com/p/codecampserver/) from [Jeffrey Palermo](http://jeffreypalermo.com/)
4. [mvcstorefront](http://blog.wekeroad.com/category/mvc-storefront) from [Rob Conery](http://blog.wekeroad.com/)
5. [ncommon](http://www.codeplex.com/ncommon) from [Ritesh Rao](http://www.codeinsanity.com/)
6. [FubuMvc](http://fubumvc.pbworks.com/) from [Chad Myers](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/chad_myers/), [Mark Nijhof](http://blog.fohjin.com/), [Jeremy Miller](http://codebetter.com/blogs/jeremy.miller/) etc

Comment: +1 Good list, but note that FubuMvc is not based on ASP.NET MVC

Comment: Yeah I like to be nice to the alt.net camp :P In the FubuMvc Contrib project there will be some nice examples albeit basic examples of using nhibernate as well as fluent nhibernate - which is related to modeling

Answer (score 0):

If you're curious, why don't you try it out? Create or use a complex database and try to prototype some basic crud operation on this DB using ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 0):

Also have a look at:

[MVC: How to work with entities with many child entities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931521/mvc-how-to-work-with-entities-with-many-child-entities)

In the end it still comes down to CRUD operations on your models. 
The only question is how not to organize it in such a way that it doesn't become a mess. I find the use of [Areas](http://haacked.com/archive/0001/01/01/areas-in-aspnetmvc.aspx) (planned to be build in to the next version of MVC) very handy.

Answer (score 0):

I would say http://orchard.codeplex.com/ is one of the more complex open source MVC apps I've seen.