# ASP.NET MVC Open Source Real-world Apps

Tags: asp.net-mvc, open-source

Whenever I start learning a new technology or language I tend to look at the source code of some 'real-world' applications. I find them really useful for understanding common, technology specific architecture, idioms and how/what popular libraries are used.
I've recently started learning ASP.NET MVC, but haven't really found good open source apps. I was wondering if you know some worthwhile ones.

I am really interested in MVC apps that use IoC Dependency Injection libraries such as Windsor or StructureMap.

Comment: This should be marked Community Wiki.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here you can find [a list of asp.net mvc applications](http://www.asp.net/mvc/learn/) with source code.

- NerdDinner
- KIGG
- Contact Manager
- Storefront
- CodeCampServer
- Suteki Shop E-Commerce

Another good example not listed there is [codebettercanvas](http://code.google.com/p/codebettercanvas/)

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at [Oxite](http://www.codeplex.com/oxite):

"This is a simple blog engine written using ASP.NET MVC, and is designed with a few main goals:

- To exist as a base for our visitmix.com site and for our personal blogs (and for the blogs of other folks as well!)
- To provide an example of 'core blog functionality' in a reusable fashion. Blogs are simple and well understood by many developers, but the set of basic functions that a blog needs to implement (trackbacks, rss, comments, etc.) are fairly complex. Hopefully this code helps.
- To provide real-world code written using ASP.NET MVC that produces both valid and semantically correct markup
  "

Comment: I heard somewhere that oxite does not have good code quality. I probably heard this in some conference or meetup

Comment: I think that may have been true of early releases (and what open source project doesn't suffer from this?) but it has been extensively refactored of late, I hear.

Answer (score 3):

[Suteki Shop](http://sutekishop.co.uk/) from [Mike Hadlow](http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/) is Open source, using ASP.NET MVC, and for an IoC, Castle Windsor

http://sutekishop.co.uk/

Answer (score 2):

[CarTrackr](http://cartrackr.codeplex.com/)

Not sure if you can call other apps as open source or samples like NerdDinner etc.

Comment: I've had a look at NerdDinner and while it's useful for learning the basics, it is not a real-world application. I'll have a look at CarTracker, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

[KIGG](http://www.codeplex.com/Kigg)

KiGG is a Web 2.0 style social news web application developed in Microsoft supported technologies.

Also Check These:

[Where is an example of a Complex ASP.net MVC model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025427/where-is-an-example-of-a-complex-asp-net-mvc-model)

[What are some projects which are examples of best pratices for ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499319/what-are-some-projects-which-are-examples-of-best-pratices-for-asp-net-mvc)

[Real World ASP.NET MVC Applications with Source Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198482/real-world-asp-net-mvc-applications-with-source-code)

Comment: oops, I missed these ones. But as some of them are old posts, there may now be some new apps that did not exist at that time. Thanks Amr.

Comment: Yes, may be, but those what i remember now, also note that stackoverflow built with MVC, while its not open source.

Answer (score 2):

Check [FlickrXplorer](http://www.codeplex.com/FlickrXplorer), which I studied first to learn MVC in ASP.Net.

(Sorry because of beeing a newbie I have to post more.)

Answer (score 2):

Checkout **MVC Storefront** on codeplex. If you google it, you can find video tutorials on how the whole project is built and what technologies are being used.

Answer (score 1):

Some people publish there solution at codeplex. [This](http://www.codeplex.com/site/search?projectSearchText=mvc%20production&sortBy=Relevance&licenses=|) is a query on codeplex looking for MVC and produktion. First is PRSync.com, there are some more.

Other is MVC storefront, but this is real academic to show building MVC applications.

Comment: Stackoverflow is build with asp.net mvc.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the Demo project Source code from 
    http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/MVC-4-Razor-Design-Sample-0ed5e9da#content